# Laravel elastic search display relevant data in top order

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

This is regarding to order the elastic search results in custom order.

I have city ids(integers) in my elastic search index, based on the user city selection the elastic search  should happen.

For example:
Consider the id of Chennai is 1 & Mumbai is 2

If we have 10 records for Chennai and 20 records for Mumbai in elastic index. If the user choose Chennai, we should display the 10 records belongs to Chennai in top order and then display the remaining items.

If the user choose Mumbai, we should display the 20 records belongs to Mumbai in top order and then display the remaining items.

I am using sleimanx2/plastic laravel package for search. Appreciate if anyone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you wish to achieve this with elastic?

The mentioned case seems to me like something i would achieve with two queries. One for the promoted, let's call them results, and one that would match everything else, except those that belong to the first query.
Then I would go ahead and display them to their respective areas or whatever.

There might be a way to merge those queries together and get your results as buckets that you can later use to create your markup accordingly, but honestly I am not sure that there is a reason to do it like this.

I hope I do not misunderstand your question,

Best Regards.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct Anagnostopoulos. I need to paginate the data also. Please suggest me to do this

Comment: Well it strongly depends on what other technologies you use. Are you using vue, are you willing to add the front end tech to the mix, or do you think it will add a lot of overhead to the result's performance. I have no clue what your dataset's size is, so those things, you have to assert for yourself. 
Also do you want the pagination to be combined or do you want the selected items to be paginated separately from the rest?